# ogr2ogr srs options: where is the well known definition determined?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, coordinate-system, srid

In the [ogr2ogr documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) it says that when using `-a_srs srs_def`:

> Srs_def can be a full WKT definition (hard to escape properly), or a well known definition (ie. EPSG:4326) or a file with a WKT definition.

Where are the default well-known definitions listed? 
Do they include ESRI as well as EPSG? 
If not, why not, and can I add all the ESRI definitions listed at [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org)? 
Is there an easy way to load an srs definition using an SRID from a PostGIS spatial_ref_sys table, aside from just running some sql to get the text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well known definitions are in the gdal/data directory.  You can browse the current directory source online: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/data. Look at the gcs.csv and pcs.csv files.

Comment: Thank you Sasa, that's exactly what I was looking for! It looks like the ESRI ones are included (at least with this build) in [esri_extra.wkt](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/data/esri_extra.wkt)

Comment: and esri_StatePlane_extra.wkt.

Answer (score 11):

I would note that if you have curl support in your GDAL build (a very common configuration), you can simply give the spatialreference.org URL for the SRS and it will fetch what it needs and dereference it appropriately.

```
-a_srs http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/ -t_srs http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26915
```

Comment: Note, spatialreference.org is very precise with urls, need to end with slash; http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326// works, http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326 wouldnt