# What is the best way to programmatically convert between WKT and Proj4 string?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, well-known-text, proj

Some shapefiles have a .prj file associated with it, and the .prj file contains the projection info of the shapefile in the format of WKT. 
Sometimes I need to convert WKT to proj4 string, and sometimes I need to convert it back.

Is there any ready-made library to do this?

Answer (score 14):

The OGR Spatial Reference part of GDAL should do the trick. capooti provided [an excellent answer to another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table/7615#7615) which demonstrates how to peform the translation from a shapefile to WKT. You may also want to check out the [class reference](https://gdal.org/api/ogrspatialref.html). The reverse is simply:

```
from osgeo import osr

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
wkt_text = 'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["WGS_1984",' \
           'SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],'\
           'UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]'
# Imports WKT to Spatial Reference Object
srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt_text)
srs.MorphToESRI() # converts the WKT to an ESRI-compatible format
print "ESRI compatible WKT for use as .prj:" % srs.ExportToWkt()
```

Comment: Anyone have a solution that doesn't require `osgeo`, which doesn't seem to work for Python 3?

Comment: OP asked about Proj4. Did you mean `ExportToProj4()` in the last line instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [PyCRS](https://github.com/karimbahgat/PyCRS):

```
import pycrs

print(pycrs.parser.from_esri_wkt(wkt_text).to_proj4())
# +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +a=6378137.0 +f=298.257223563 +pm=0.0  +no_defs
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any library, but you can use this site to get the translations: http://spatialreference.org/

EDIT:
I found a python script that works with ogr python bindings to do that. [Here it is](http://spatialnotes.blogspot.com/2010/11/converting-wkt-projection-info-to-proj4.html).

Comment: thanks, but i need to do that programmatically.

Comment: After some googling: spatialreference.org is powered by GDAL as well & uses the same code path (more or less), it seems.

Comment: That's interesting

Answer (score 0):

I need to pragrammatically transform to custom projection based on proj4text string, so used

```
projection = '+proj=lcc +lat_1=53 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=136 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs'
```

`source = osr.SpatialReference() 
 source.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
 target = osr.SpatialReference()
 target.ImportFromProj4(projection)
 transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)`