# Convert WKT coordinate reference system to PROJ4

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proj, well-known-text, las

I'm currently working on a better support of LAS 1.4 file format in the `rlas` R package. In LAS 1.4 format the CRS of the point cloud can be stored as a WKT string. For example this is what I read from a LAS 1.4 file (raw data).

```
"COMPD_CS[\"Projected\", PROJCS[\"UTM_10N\", GEOGCS [ \"WGS84\", DATUM [ \"WGS84\", SPHEROID [\"WGS 84\", 6378137.000, 298.257223563 ], TOWGS84 [ 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.0000000000, 0.0000000000, 0.0000000000, 0.0000000000 ] ], PRIMEM [ \"Greenwich\", 0.000000 ], UNIT [ \"metres\", 1.00000000] ], PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"], PARAMETER[\"Latitude_of_Origin\",0.0000000000], PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-123.0000000000], PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996000000], PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.000], PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.000], UNIT [ \"metres\", 1.00000000]] ], VERT_CS[\"NAVD88 (Geoid03) ContUS\", VERT_DATUM[\"./Resources/CoordSysData/navd88_geo03_contus.bin\", 1 ], UNIT [ \"metres\", 1.00000000] ] ]"
```

How can I interpret this string in R? In the R spatial ecosystem all packages rely on PROJ4. How I can convert this WKT string into PROJ4 string?

`geos::readWKT` does not understand this string.

Comment: There's some python solutions here that don't require lookups of any data base and work by converting the string format: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8547/what-is-the-best-way-to-programmatically-convert-between-wkt-and-proj4-string - the osgeo lib works on your example. If you can call python from R then that might be a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `rgdal` package and `showP4`:

Your string:

```
> ps
[1] "COMPD_CS[\"Projected\", PROJCS[\"UTM_10N\", GEOGCS [ \"WGS84\", DATUM [ \"WGS84\", SPHEROID [\"WGS 84\", 6378137.000, 298.257223563 ], TOWGS84 [ 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.0000000000, 0.0000000000, 0.0000000000, 0.0000000000 ] ], PRIMEM [ \"Greenwich\", 0.000000 ], UNIT [ \"metres\", 1.00000000] ], PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"], PARAMETER[\"Latitude_of_Origin\",0.0000000000], PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-123.0000000000], PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996000000], PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.000], PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.000], UNIT [ \"metres\", 1.00000000]] ], VERT_CS[\"NAVD88 (Geoid03) ContUS\", VERT_DATUM[\"./Resources/CoordSysData/navd88_geo03_contus.bin\", 1 ], UNIT [ \"metres\", 1.00000000] ] ]"
```

Your string as a Proj4 string:

```
> showP4(ps)
[1] "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-7047.380880109124 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0.000,0.000,0.000,0.0000000000,0.0000000000,0.0000000000,0.0000000000 +units=m +no_defs "
```

Or using the `sf` package with `st_crs` and the `wkt=` parameter:

```
> st_crs(wkt=ps)
Coordinate Reference System:
  No EPSG code
  proj4string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-7047.380880109124 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0.000,0.000,0.000,0.0000000000,0.0000000000,0.0000000000,0.0000000000 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Note I'm not convinced every parameter is always handled or converted properly... Caveat emptor.

Comment: I searched in `rgdal` but `showP4` is not a trivial name. Thanks. That should make the job.

Comment: Its not obvious - the `sf` package has an improved interface and names. `??wkt` finds `showWKT` as "Show Well-Known Text spatial reference system metadata" and the help for that lists `showP4` as well. Think thats the roundabout route that led me to it.

Comment: There is a problem in the WKT definition, at `GEOGCS [ ... , UNIT [ "metres" , 1.00000000 ] ], ...`. The units of the GEOGCS must be `["degree", 0.01745329251994328]`. Thats why the central meridian is converted to `+lon_0=-7047.380880109124`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the WKT tells you about WGS84 UTM 10N, try http://epsg.io/32610 as a start-off.

For the vertical datum, see https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki/VerticalDatums