# Matching ArcGIS and QGIS coordinate systems

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I have the following info for a feature class in ArcGIS that is supposed to be in WGS 1984/UTM 16N ***projected*** coordinate system:

> Projection: Transverse_Mercator
>
> False_Easting: 500000.000000
>
> False_Northing: 0.000000
>
> Central_Meridian: -87.000000
>
> Scale_Factor: 0.999600
>
> Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.000000
>
> Linear Unit: Meter (1.000000)
>
> Geographic Coordinate System:
>   GCS_WGS_1984
>
> Angular Unit: Degree
>   (0.017453292519943299)
>
> Prime Meridian: Greenwich
>   (0.000000000000000000)
>
> Datum: D_WGS_1984
>
> Spheroid: WGS_1984
>
> Semimajor Axis: 6378137.000000000000000000
>
> Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314245179300000000
>
> Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563000030000

I also have a vector shapefile imported into QGIS that is also supposed to be projected WGS 1984/UTM 16N, with the EPSG 32616 and ID 3100.

Since I don't know what the EPSG and ID means, I am not sure if the shapefile in QGIS and the feature class in ArcGIS are actually in the same coordinate system.

Can anyone help with this? And if they are *not* in the same system, what should I do to correct that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here EPSG:32616 WKT, both are same

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N", 
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
  SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", -87.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
UNIT["m", 1.0], 
AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32616"]]
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you get the "EPSG:32616 WKT"?

Comment: I have SRS reference list in GeoServer and had look that. However these are standard reference and available in web too. Check : http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32616/html/

Comment: there are some other good references for getting this info at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table

Comment: Definitive reference is the EPSG registry ~ https://www.epsg-registry.org/ note that the EPSG registry tells us the axis order ~https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32616