# Testing if two GDAL datasets are in same projection

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I'm attemping to write a function to test if a list of datasets are in the same projection.  Naively, I thought I could test the text of WKTs, but that does not work in the following case:

'PROJCS["**NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N**",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983", ...'

'PROJCS["**NAD83 / UTM zone 14N**",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983", ...'

Even though the projections are identical, and the rest of the WKT is identical, the tags leading them are not which makes me wonder if there is a formal mechanism for testing the equality of projection systems.

I am programming with the GDAL extensions in Python.

Answer (score 6):

Try importing the WKT into an GDAL/OSR SpatialReference object, and compare the non-zero SRIDs. It is much simpler to compare two integers than to compare two text markups.

Look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table) to [Shapefile PRJ to PostGIS SRID lookup table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7608/115) to get an idea how to use GDAL for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

To add to [@Mike T's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/50314/115), GDAL/OSR SpatialReference object has a `IsSame()` function that can be used in Python GDAL like so:

```
from osgeo import osr

spref1 = osr.SpatialReference()
spref1.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

spref2 = osr.SpatialReference()
spref2.ImportFromEPSG(4269)

comparison = spref1.IsSame(spref2)
```

If the value of comparison is `1` then it is the same spatial reference. In the above example, it will return `0`.