# How to import multiple shapefiles each with different source projections to postgis

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, import, srid

I have a couple thousand .zip files each with a .shp, .dbf, .shx, and .prj inside them that I want to load into postgis. The problem is, they have many different source projections (each defined in the .prj file).

Is there any way to load them all at once without having to manually set the projection for each file?

Comment: With Python yes, See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table

Comment: @Mapperz link is good. after loading data into PostGIS you just do 'UPDATE table SET geom = ST_Transform(geom, wanted_proj)