# How can I get the proj4 string or EPSG code from a shapefile .prj file?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, coordinate-system, proj

I have to work with a shapefile defined in an unusual projection, which my GIS software does not know about. How can I get the proj4 definition or the EPSG code for the projection?

Comment: Check online EPSG registry? Perhaps search by area of use. http://www.epsg-registry.org

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The shapefile should have a .prj file which defines the projection. You can use it together with one of the following 3 options to get either the proj4 string, WKT definition or EPSG code.

**To get proj4 definition:**

If you have gdal installed on your system, you can use the `gdalsrsinfo` command line application to get the proj4 definition as the OGC WKT definition:

```
$ gdalsrsinfo <shapefile>.prj
```

Exampe:

```
$ gdalsrsinfo 7490.prj 

PROJ.4 : '+proj=aea +lat_1=-18 +lat_2=-32 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_South_Africa",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",24],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",-18],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",-32],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

**To get EPSG number:**

You can use the [prj2epsg.org](http://www.prj2epsg.org/) service to upload the .prj file and get a list of matching EPSG codes. **Warning:** prj2epsg.org returns the list of codes which match *best*. It may be that none of them are correct.

**Using python:**

If you are comfortable with Python, you can use the very useful script at [Shapefile PRJ to PostGIS SRID lookup table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table/7615#7615) to get the WKT, proj4 string and EPSG code.

**See also:**

You can find definitions for most standard projections at [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/).

Comment: This works also with a geo-referenced raster file, such as TIFF: gdalsrsinfo filename.tif

Answer (score 5):

The gdal app gdalsrsinfo produces many different representations of an srs:

```
kyle@kyle-hp-desktop:~$ gdalsrsinfo epsg:4326 -o all

PROJ.4 : '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

OGC WKT (simple) :
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]

OGC WKT (no CT) :
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]

ESRI WKT :
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

...
```

You can input proj.4 strings, wkt strings or epsg codes.  Since gdal 1.9 (I think).

Answer (score 3):

I've always used `grep` to grab this information:

```
ogrinfo -so <shapefile>.shp | grep -e "ESPG"
```

Comment: only possible in linux :)

Comment: and Mac OS X :)

Comment: and Windows, using MobaXterm ;-)

Comment: I don't think this actually works, on none of the platforms, as `gdalinfo` does not read shape files. And if you meant `gdalsrsinfo`, that does not always return an EPSG code in its output.

Comment: @j08lue: they probably meant `ogrinfo` (edited).