# Determining the SRID of a dataset in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, spatial-database

Sometimes the dataset provides some information about its projection. For example, it can mention `Horizontal_Datum_Name: North American Datum of 1983`, `Ellipsoid_Name: GRS1980`, `Geographic_Coordinate_Units: Decimal degrees`.

How do you determine the SRID? Doing the following query does not seem to work all the time (like this query itself returns no result)

```
SELECT srid, srtext,proj4text
FROM spatial_ref_sys
WHERE proj4text ILIKE '%nad83%'
AND proj4text ILIKE '%grs80%' AND proj4text ILIKE '%longlat%';
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have a record that matches all your criteria? You are looking for a SRS that has all three strings in its text representation. Does such a SRS exist?

Comment: Yup it exists, SRID 4269. Wondering if theres a systematic approach for determining the SRID

Comment: Have you looked at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608