# Find unit of EPSG-Code

Tags: coordinate-system, java, ogr, epsg, osgeo

I need a way to find out the unit of an EPSG-Code (e.g: meter) from java (ogr, gdal, osgeo?) but any other approach would be fine as well.
I want to do something like:

```
if(epsg.unit==meter){
   do this
} else {
   do that
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table

Comment: how you do this is pretty dependent on the software package you are using, OGR will be different to GeoTools which is different to OpenJump etc.

Comment: @JohnBarça thanks but there were a lot of things that I did not understand (since I am new to GIS) but I managed to solve my problem.

Comment: or you could try parsing the definition file for the EPSG code directly: http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/27700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the ogr java bindings:

```
public static void unitOfCRS(){
        SpatialReference poSourceSRS = new SpatialReference();
        // output: metre
        poSourceSRS.ImportFromEPSG(3068);
        System.out.println(poSourceSRS.GetAttrValue("UNIT"));
        // output: degree
        poSourceSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326);
        System.out.println(poSourceSRS.GetAttrValue("UNIT"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps look into the [PROJ4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) library. There seems to be a [Java binding](http://www.geoapi.org/geoapi-proj4/), which you could use.

I am almost confident that I have done a similar task before, although with Python, but I cannot find my code to double check.

Either way, there should be a way to get a string which includes all the parameters of a specific coordinate system. You would then use that string to extract your units.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that looks promising but the installation of the java binding together with the proj4 library was a little bit too much, I found out that I can solve my problem with the ogr java bindings (which I already have installed).